# Storing images not as part of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, assets

I am building my new site and have a small group of images I want to display on the site.

They are not images to do with styling so it feels wrong to store them within the app/assets directory

I don't wish to put them on my Flickr account which builds by apps gallery as they are not that type of image.

I currently have them stored on an Amazon S3 bucket and link to them from there.

is there a better way. What way would you guys choose?

If I am already using the best way, is it worth linking to them using the standard url Amazon provides me with or should I direct one of my URL's to that point?

Comment: Can you give any more context as to the purpose of the images?

Comment: What about the /public directory?

Comment: The images are single images of individual roller coasters. I don't want them in the gallery as each one has a specially formatted filename that the app constructs to show that photo on their individual pages. If I put them inside the app then they end up in source control and I was told that was a bad idea?

Comment: You can exclude specific files and directories from source control using `.gitignore` for example if you're using git.  I'm sure there will be similar ways in other source control systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice for Amazon S3 seems fine to me, and no, you should not change the standard URL's Amazon provides you with. Advantage is that your own web server is not bothered by the image URL's anymore!

I have a similar website storing "dynamic" pictures, and I keep them on cloudinary, which is a similar site. Your source directory should not in general store these "dynamic" pictures. They only consume disk space, and sites like Amazon S3 and Cloudinary are made just for that!

Comment: Sticking with S3 for those assets. Thanks for your advice.